# How can I preg_match a Stellar public address in PHP?

Tags: payments, security

Just wondering if anyone can help me preg_match a Stellar public address in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

A stellar address begins with "G", followed by "[A-D]" and then 54 characters from this base32 alphabet "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567]", so:

```
preg_match('/^G[ABCD]{1}[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567]{54}$/', $s);
```

However you could also use this [php sdk](https://github.com/zulucrypto/stellar-api) like this:

```
  try {
        $key = \ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\Keypair::newFromPublicKey($s);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
        exit('Invalid Address: ' . $s);
   }
```